# How would I loop through an array of objects and check for existence of key- or value parameter?

Tags: arrays, loops, object, indexing

Given this Array (key / value pairs):

```
 var array = [ 
    {name:  'Antonello',            location:'Barcelona'}, 
    {email: 'george@george.com',    name:'George'}, 
        {name:  'Mike',             coder: true}
    ]
```

how would a function look like that finds the element in an array of objects and returns the index (or -1 if no element of this kind).

NOTICE: this is a beginners exercise and no use of ES6 or findIndex.

This is my code. I want to check if either the key or the value is undefined. If not, return the array index.

```
function getIndex(array, key, value) {
    var indexFound = 0;
    for (var index in array) {
        if (array[index].key == undefined && array[index].value == undefined) {
            var indexFound = -1;
        } else {
            var indexFound = array[index];
        }
    }
    return indexFound
}
```

This is the function with the 3 parameters getIndex(array, key, value).

Expected outcome:

`getIndex(array, "name", "Antonello")` should return 0.
`getIndex(array, "coder", false) should` return -1.

Comment: Just to go sure, for this call:

`getIndex([{name:'Antonello', location:'Barcelona'},{email: 'george@george.com', name:'George'},{name:'Mike', coder: true}], 'name', 'Antonello')`

I get -1 whereas it should be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of  `for...in` loop is wrong, check the documentation here, [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Although you can use for..in loop for iterating over the array, important thing to note here from Mozilla docs is:-[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in)

> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and are otherwise identical to general object properties. There is no guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular order. The for...in loop statement will return all enumerable properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are inherited.
>
> Because the order of iteration is implementation-dependent, iterating over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore, it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index (or Array.prototype.forEach() or the for...of loop) when iterating over arrays where the order of access is important.
>
> ```js
> var array = [{
>     name: 'Antonello',
>     location: 'Barcelona'
>   },
>   {
>     email: 'george@george.com',
>     name: 'George'
>   },
>   {
>     name: 'Mike',
>     coder: true
>   }
> ];
>
> function getIndex(array, key, value) {
>   var indexFound = -1;
>   array.forEach((obj, index) => {
>     if (obj[key] !== undefined && obj[key] === value) {
>       indexFound = index;
>     }
>   });
>   return indexFound;
> }
>
>
> var foundIndex = getIndex(array, 'name', 'Antonello');
> console.log(foundIndex);
> ```

Comment: "Given that for...in is built for iterating object properties, not recommended for use with arrays, a ..." do you mean this?

Comment: That too, but as you want to iterate over all the elements of the array, and need the "index" neither for...in nor for...of suits your need here. As none of these provide you the index value.

Comment: Thx ... can you elaborate the logic in the if condition pls? why strict equal and why in that combo?

Comment: Using strict equality is a best practice that we should always try to follow when working with type equality checking in JavaScript. It was not necessary to make the undefined check here though, we can do without that also.

Comment: ok, but what exactly am I checking? with: obj[key] === value

Do I check if there is a fitting pair which returns true?

Comment: forEach() passes the array element with its index to the callback function. Array element = “obj” (note: each element is an object in this case). Now to check whether the object has a particular value for the passes key from the getIndex(array, key, value) function. We are doing the equality check. Also, note that, to use variable as key, we had to use obj[key] syntax not obj.key. “obj[key]” translates to “obj.name” in this case(as key = “name”)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199208/discussion-between-expertnoob-and-user2132380).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [ 
    {name:  'Antonello',            location:'Barcelona'}, 
    {email: 'george@george.com',    name:'George'}, 
    {name:  'Mike',             coder: true}
];

function getIndex(array, key, value) {
    var indexFound = -1;
    array.forEach(function(obj, index) {
        if (typeof obj[key] !== 'undefined' && obj[key] === value) {
            indexFound = index;
        }
    });
    return indexFound;
}

console.log(getIndex(array, "name", "Antonello"));
console.log(getIndex(array, "email", "george@george.com"));
console.log(getIndex(array, "coder", false));
```